# Best way to get word frequency counts for a website? Or part of a website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

Pretty simple, I just looking for a simple means of extracting word frequencies from a given website, or section of a website.

I am also interested in calculating average distance between two given words throughout a website. The units of distance being in words.

I am asking this question because I quite frankly haven't been able to find much information leading to the intuition of performing such a task. I don't have any experience with web spidering or scraping of any kind.

Thanks (I asked this question earlier, but it wasn't well formed)

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas by searching 'python str_word_count'. (str_word_count is a PHP function which return number of words counts of string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use  [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org). It is quite powerful tool for scrapping websites, but may require knowledge of regular expressions and XPath. Try to follow [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/tutorial.html).